# Reformatting of SQL Query, possible Pivot

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

[image: Query]

The image shows my query with two tables and the output.  Instead of the output being in the format in the image I need it as follows.

```
Date Time   |   Load Cell 0   |   Load Cell 1
----------------------------------------------
03/06/2016         12                14
08/07/2016          4                7
```

I believe I may need to use a Pivot ????  but i am just stuck with how to do that.

I am doing this in Visual Studio for a C# Windows Forms App and the data is to be shown in a datagrid and used for a graph/chart.  The db used is a MS SQL CE file.

If anyone could help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(test.datetime as date) [date], 
sum(case when loads.loads_cell = 0 then loads.kN end) [Load Cell 0], 
sum(case when loads.loads_cell = 1 then loads.kN end) [Load Cell 1]
from loads 
join tests on loads.test_id = tests.tests_id
group by cast(test.datetime as date)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it avoids having to use PIVOT which is unavailable in MSSQL CE.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in believing this could be benefited from PIVOT.

```
SELECT TestDate, pvt.[0], pvt.[1]
FROM (
     SELECT t.DateTime as TestDate, l.Load_Cell_ID as LCID, l.kn
     FROM loads as l
     INNER JOIN Tests as t on l.Test_ID = t.Test_ID
     ) as inr
PIVOT (
     SUM(kn) FOR LCID in ([0], [1]) --specify additional load cell ids here
) as pvt
```

That being said, I am not certain that SQL CE has the pivot operator.  You may have to go with a nested query, as t-clausen.dk suggested.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know you could use a nested query there.  Thanks, Kamil.

Comment: Sorry, pivot without known column names is impossible. You have to use dynamic SQL. I deleted my wrong comment.

Comment: Haha, that's dissapointing.  I have several reports that require dynamic SQL to accomplish that.

Comment: Damn database software developers. Servers have so many fancy functions, full text search, xml handling, but dynamic IN() with pivot is impossible. Even in Oracle. I understand that its hard to implement, maybe not efficient, but they could do something...

Answer (score 0):

I think if you dont know column names in advance - in your case PIVOT in SQL is not an option.

I would recommend you to pivot that data programatically in C# (dont bind datagridview with query data, bind it with empty datatable object and fill that datatable programatically).

Added later:

You asked in comments how to start.

Take a look at this: [C# pivot table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22008/C-Pivot-Table)

Maybe it looks complicated, but almost "ready to use".

Comment: I think this is what i need to do, im just having a mental block with where to start pivoting in C#